# Using SetTimeout to jump to a specific slide in an image gallery

Tags: javascript, html

I'm using an image gallery code that assigns an ID to each slide.  I want to make a function that when the user clicks "next" on "img-7", the user goes to "img-8" but is then sent back to "img-7" after 5 seconds.

I have "setTimeout("jump,5000")" to activate on click when the user clicks "next" on img-7, but how can I set the "jump" function?  I know that "window.location.href" is used to change windows, but how can I set it to jump to a different ID within the image gallery?

```js
function jump(){

                 }
```

```html
    <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="img-7" />
    <li class="slide-container">
<div class="video-container">
        <div class="slide">
  
  <video id="video7" width="100%"  loop muted>
          <source src="files/video/7.webm" type="video/webm"> 
    </video>
    </div>
        </div>
  <div class="nav">
   <label for="img-6" class="prev"></label>
   <label for="img-8" class="next" onclick="setTimeout(jump,5000)"></label>
  </div>

    </li>
    
         <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="img-8" />
    <li class="slide-container">
<div class="video-container">
        <div class="slide">
  
  <video id="video8" width="100%"  loop muted>
          <source src="files/video/8.webm" type="video/webm"> 
    </video>
    </div>
        </div>
  <div class="nav">
   <label for="img-7" class="prev"></label>
   <label for="img-9" class="next"></label>
  </div>

    </li>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to wrap the innards of `setTimeout` with quotations.

```
<label for="img-8" class="next" onclick="setTimeout("jump,5000")></label>
```

`onclick` is being interpreted as `onclick="setTimeout("` because the quotation by `jump` is closing off the one by `onClick`.

Instead, `onclick` should be this:

```
onclick="setTimeout(jump, 5000)"
```

Comment: Any suggestions on how I can make the function for it?  I know that "window.location.href" is used to go to different pages, but how can I make a function that jumps to an ID within the image gallery code?

Comment: @user2454060 You'd have to take a look at the image gallery's code and see how it automatically changes, then implement that somehow.

Comment: Its the code I posted, each slide has an ID (img-1,img-2, etc...).  The "prev" and "next" buttons have a label matching the ID they are going to.  I just have no idea where to start on making the function in javascript.  Its need to link to an ID rather than a URL.

Comment: @user2454060 Maybe you could use `a` instead of `label` and have the `href` go to `#img-8`? And for the seventh one, include `onclick` that calls a function that'd set the window location to itself plus `#img-7`? I don't know if it'll work.